# Swing or SWT/JFace - for integration with MS Office

Tags: swing, swt, jface

I 've read a lot of discussions about Swing vs SWT/Jface.  Yet, I have a particular need in mind and I wonder people with experiences here sould kind share your insights.

I'm planning to develop desktop application to integrate MS Office (Excel, Word, Outlook).  Which technology I should choose: Swing or SWT/Jface?

many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate [sic] MS Office"? For example, do you wish to embed an Excel spreadsheet *within* your application?

Comment: thank you for asking.  By integration, I means to operate MS office from within Java Product on Windows - open or close word, excel, outlook, transfer data etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What platform are you going to develop your desktop application on, and how much UI tweaking are you planning on doing?  It is commonly argued on the internet that SWT and JFace are more suitable for quick out-of-the-box type UI development on the Eclipse platform because they work so well together (eg. JFace wizards, databinding and validation), whereas Swing is more suitable for enterprise level development in NetBeans that requires more UI customising:

http://www.ahmadsoft.org/articles/swingswt/swingswt.html

I have worked on UI applications written in SWT and JFace with Eclipse (which consume web services), and have found such things as the decorator framework to be quite useful.  My applications require minimal user interaction, so SWT and JFace have minimized my development time quite nicely.  I can see, though that if I scaled out my application to an enterprise level MVC design requiring richer interactions with users that using SWT and JFace may not be as suitable as using Swing.

Just my opinion!

Comment: As an update to this answer, I also think now that JavaFX2 is the successor of Swing.  Oracle are pouring more resources into JavaFX2/8 and letting Swing sunset.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6